# Deleted default constructor identified as candidate in ambiguous error

Tags: c++, c++11

When attempting to delete the default constructor and provide a new one with a default parameter (and therefore still be able to default construct the object), I receive an ambiguity error from g++.

```
class Thing
{
  public:
    Thing() = delete;
    Thing(int arg = 0) : arg(arg) {}
  private:
    int arg;
};

int main(int, char**)
{
  Thing thing;
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation error below:

```
$ g++ deletedConstructorTest.C -std=c++11 
deletedConstructorTest.C: In function "int main(int, char**)": 
deletedConstructorTest.C:12:9: error: call of overloaded "Thing()" is ambiguous
     Thing thing;
         ^  
deletedConstructorTest.C:12:9: note: candidates are:  
deletedConstructorTest.C:5:5: note: Thing::Thing(int)
     Thing(int arg = 0) :arg(arg) {}
     ^  
deletedConstructorTest.C:4:5: note: Thing::Thing() <deleted>
     Thing() = delete;
     ^
```

If I modify the example above by removing the "Thing() = delete;" line then it compiles fine. I understand that the compiler won't generate a default constructor since I provided my own so that line is unnecessary but I was surprised at the compilation error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: you don't need to delete the default constructor here, by creating another constructor it is already deleted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All declared overloads are considered during overload resolution, even if they are deleted or inaccessible. So you've declared two default constructors, both of which are an equally good match for default-initialisation, hence the ambiguity.

In this case, simply don't declare the zero-argument default constructor at all. The one-argument constructor is usable as a default constructor, and declaring any constructor inhibits the generation of an implicit default constructor.

Comment: I guess my real question is: why are deleted constructors considered? It was clear based on the compiler output that both were looked at but it just seems odd that I can't explicitly delete the default constructor in this case.

Comment: @DaveEhrenberger: My view is that deleted (and inaccessible) functions are for preventing operations; in which you'd want them to match, but be rejected, rather than just be excluded from the overload set, potentially allowing the operation via another overload. But I've no idea whether that's got anything to do with the language designers' rationale for this decision.